# Include results where COUNT() = 0

Tags: php, mysql, count

To select a table field with the count. That part is working. I also need to include result where the count is 0

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT mallname, COUNT( * ) AS Count
FROM `malls`
INNER JOIN Mal_Client_Relationship ON Mal_Client_Relationship.m_Id = malls.m_Id
INNER JOIN clients ON Mal_Client_Relationship.id_user = clients.id_user
INNER JOIN dates ON dates.date_id = Mal_Client_Relationship.date_id
WHERE confirmcode = 'y' && EndDate >= CURRENT_DATE( ) || HAVING count(*) = 0
GROUP BY `mallname`
ORDER BY `mallname`
```

And

```
SELECT mallname, COUNT( * ) AS Count
FROM `malls`
INNER JOIN Mal_Client_Relationship ON Mal_Client_Relationship.m_Id = malls.m_Id
INNER JOIN clients ON Mal_Client_Relationship.id_user = clients.id_user
INNER JOIN dates ON dates.date_id = Mal_Client_Relationship.date_id
WHERE confirmcode = 'y' && EndDate >= CURRENT_DATE( ) || count(*) = 0
GROUP BY `mallname`
ORDER BY `mallname`
```

And

```
SELECT mallname, COUNT( * ) AS Count
FROM `malls`
INNER JOIN Mal_Client_Relationship ON Mal_Client_Relationship.m_Id = malls.m_Id
INNER JOIN clients ON Mal_Client_Relationship.id_user = clients.id_user
INNER JOIN dates ON dates.date_id = Mal_Client_Relationship.date_id
WHERE confirmcode = 'y' && EndDate >= CURRENT_DATE( ) || count(mallname) = 0
GROUP BY `mallname`
ORDER BY `mallname`
```

To shed some light on the logic behind it. When the count reach 60 (60 clients) I need to disable the mallname. I do that in php, which is working. But I need include mallname with a 0 count (which means the mall has no clients link to it yet.

Hope that all make sense ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face is that certain groups (mall names) are being dropped in the event that they have a zero count.  One solution to this problem is to first select all mall names and then `LEFT JOIN` this result to the results obtained from grouping by each mall name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.mallname, COALESCE(t.Count, 0)
FROM `malls` m LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT mallname, COUNT( * ) AS Count
    FROM `malls`
    INNER JOIN Mal_Client_Relationship ON Mal_Client_Relationship.m_Id = malls.m_Id
    INNER JOIN clients ON Mal_Client_Relationship.id_user = clients.id_user
    INNER JOIN dates ON dates.date_id = Mal_Client_Relationship.date_id
    WHERE confirmcode = 'y' && EndDate >= CURRENT_DATE( ) || HAVING count(*) = 0
    GROUP BY `mallname`
    ORDER BY `mallname`
) t
ON m.mallname = t.mallname
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks